# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow - approve/reject reason

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a simple workflow with an approval process. After creating a new custom list item, the workflow assigns a task for a specified user for accepting or rejecting this new item.

By default, the approver can click Approve or Reject button.

How to add a textbox, so the approver can write a reason for approving/rejecting the entry? And how to insert this reason to a proper column in this new item?

It is Sharepoint 2013 workflow model.

Comment: Which workflow model are you using 2010 or 2013?

Comment: It is SharePoint 2013 model

Answer (score 1):

you can use the description field of the task form , asking approvers to write his comments there and then set the list item column i.e "approver comments" with the value of the task description field